# Property 'Y' does not exist on type "'Component name'" in AOT build

Tags: angular

I got  `Property 'Y' does not exist on type 'Component name'` exception when trying to build in AOT.

ExampleComponent.html

```
<header [EXAMPLE1]="Y" [EXAMPLE2]="Y"></header>
```

Header.ts

```
@Input() public EXAMPLE1: string = "N";
@Input() public EXAMPLE2: string = "N";
```

When trying to serve or build JIT it working fine.but when trying to AOT build i got this exception.

Comment: show your `ExampleComponent` code and fields declared on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You bind the value of `Y` property to the `EXAMPLE1` and `EXAMPLE2`. And you don't have that property, so the error is correct. You need to bind either `"'Y'"` as string or remove the `[]` part from the properties.

```
<header [EXAMPLE1]="'Y'" [EXAMPLE2]="'Y'"></header>
```

or

```
<header EXAMPLE1="Y" EXAMPLE2="Y"></header>
```

Comment: Thanks bro @Suren Srapyan

Comment: Thanks for this, I was stuck on it for a while. I was just parsing a string literal and after reading this realised angular thought i was parsing a variable.